# How to insert dynamic data (HTML) into SendGrid Templates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I wish to send an email using a ***SendGrid*** template. 
I use the standard v3 api and a simple axios call.

I wish to send an email using a Template.
The mail should contain a number of rows and columns. 
I do not know how many rows/column there will be when creating the Template. 
The number of rows/columns will depend on data only known when composing the email.

In my code I wish to:

1. Collect data and compose as many rows/columns as I wish using HTML or other recommended method.
2. Compose the message using Template and insert my HTML from (1) into the Template using  "personalisations/dynamic_template_data" or any other recommended method.
3. Send the email.
4. I expect the email to treat my HTML rows/columns as HTML.

My code (does not work - HTML is treated as text):

```
  //Coompose HTML
  let alertHtml = ''
  noteObjArray.forEach((nototObj)=>{
    ...
    alertHtml += (myDate !== '') ? `- ${someText} ${myDate } ` : ''
    ...
    alertHtml += '<br/>'
  })

  //Send mail using SendGrid  
  const mailSender = firebaseFunctionsConfig.sendgrid.sender
  const msg = {
    personalizations: [{
      to: [{email, name}],
      dynamic_template_data: {userName:name, amount, alertHtml}
    }],
    from: {email: mailSender.email, name: mailSender.name},
    reply_to: {email: mailSender.replyemail, name: mailSender.replyname},
    template_id: 'a-000078d4b2eb666940bbg1ee66s'
    // "content": [{"type": "text/html"}] 
  }
```

Thanks in advance! /K

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To be able to insert HTML into a ***SendGrid*** template you simply have to insert the variable using **three** curly braces in the template instead of the standard **two**.

In the SendGrid Template - this syntax will interpret the variable `textRows` as plain text

```
{{textRows}}
```

In the SendGrid Template - this ayntax will interpret the variable `textRows` as HTML

```
{{{textRows}}}
```

Thanks to Kyle Roberts for posting the solution on [github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/738)!

/K

Comment: That's so insanely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Very helpful. ChatGPT was not able to fix this for me and I have to come here and got solution in 2 mins.

Comment: The link does not work anymore.